# How to run a function every 10 minutes, on the 10 minute mark, 6 times per hour?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function run at 1:00, 1:10, 1:20, 1:30... all day regardless of when the page was initially loaded. I know how to use `setInterval` to make it run every 10 minutes, but how can I synchronize the first execution to the correct time to achieve what I'm trying to do? For example, if the page is loaded at 1:27, I'd like the first execution to occur at 1:30, and then the next at 1:40, next at 1:50, etc.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did one or more of the answers below answer your question?  If so, please select one as the best answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer to indicate to the community that your question has now been answered.  If not, then please explain in a comment back to me what has not been answered yet.

Answer (score 6):

```
var d = new Date();
var epoch = d.getTime() / 1000;

var secondsSinceLastTimerTrigger = epoch % 600; // 600 seconds (10 minutes)
var secondsUntilNextTimerTrigger = 600 - secondsSinceLastTimerTrigger;

setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(myFunction, 600*1000);
    myFunction();
}, secondsUntilNextTimerTrigger*1000);
```

Comment: Why do you throw away the milliseconds accuracy?

Comment: Oh well I hadn't considered that lol, I'm just used to retrieving the epoch in seconds not milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say just get the time until the next 10 minute mark. Then, set a `setTimeout` to start your interval:

```
var now = new Date();
var min = now.getMinutes();
var startIn = 10 - (min % 10);
console.log('Start in ' + startIn + ' minutes');
setTimeout(runInterval, startIn * 60 * 1000);
function runInterval() {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log('run');
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/

Cron jobs!  I would say more, but the linked website even generates the patterns for you.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the time left between when you loaded the page and the first epoch.  Use `setTimeout` to execute a `setInterval` that runs at an interval of the epoch, thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that calculates the delta in ms until the next 10 minute boundary:

```
function calcTimeToNextTenMinuteBoundary() {
    var now = new Date();
    var next = new Date();
    next.setSeconds(0);
    next.setMilliseconds(0);
    var tenPeriodStart = Math.round(now.getMinutes() / 10) * 10;
    next.setMinutes(tenPeriodStart + 10);
    // return ms to next 10 minute boundary
    return next - now;
}
```

You can call this at any time to see how much time to set your next timer for.  It would be preferable not to use `setInterval()`, but to rather set a new `setTimeout()` for each next timer so there is no chance for accumulating error over time.

Because this uses the `Date()` object and it's minute calculations, it even takes into account leap seconds that are occasionally added to a given year which direct calculations from the epoch start time won't account for.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zhwLbre7/ (you have to wait until the next 10 minute time boundary to see anything).